# Haskell - lacks of accompanyng binding

Tags: haskell

```
genSuffixes::[Char]->[[Char]]
getSuffixes (xs) = suffix 0 (xs)
suffix::Int->[Char]->[[Char]]
suffix n (xs) = if n==length(xs)
           then(xs)
           else drop n (xs) ++ suffix (n+1) (xs)
```

I get "The type signature of `genSuffixes` lacks of accompanyng bindings", when trying to compile the code.

Comment: It's ok to be dyslexic, but it's a problem you have to recognize to live with it.

Answer (score 3):

Check your spelling: you give a type signature for `genSuffixes` (with an `n`), but a definition for `getSuffixes` (with a `t`).

Answer (score 2):

You have misspelled one of `genSuffixes` or `getSuffixes`.